# How to batch convert .docx to .doc using Automator?

Tags: automator, ms-office, file-conversion

I'm looking for a good way to batch convert .docx to .doc, which is necessary as there are many issues when importing more recent Word files into InDesign.

I've tried the built in command line tool textutil but for some reason it is stripping all of the footnootes and endnotes off of the documents. I've also seen various answers to this question, however, they are from many years ago and I can't seem to get them to work.

Is there a good way to use Automator to convert a folder of .docx files to .doc while preserving references? Thanks in advance!

Comment: A docx file is a zipped XML file, does MS even release the format to non-developers? Unless you have a parser that can handle docx files you will probably find it works best to Applescript a workflow that loads the docx file into MS Word and then save it as a doc file.

Comment: [A SO question about Office 365 API's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22666233/463206). Researching the API however feels more like reading a car parts catalog when you want to know how to rebuild your engine.